What are the latex codes for logical connectives for and, or?
I want to write the symbols for 'and', and 'or'.  What are they in Latex?

Welcome! Which symbols for them? Different systems use different symbols ....

\land and \lor
Make sure to use them in math mode.

How do you use math mode? I tried them inside $ but it didn't work.

@leepappas Math mode is triggered by $...$, \[...\] or math environments like equation, align and so on. $A \land B$ and $A \lor B$ don't like you expected?

It worked, thank you

These will only give the correct symbols if they happen to match the system you're using. There is not one symbol for each connective but several and different systems make different choices. (@leepappas)
